# Why cant i use `props.data` in my CountUp component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following component. The reason for creating this was not to repeat my self too much.

```
const InsightCard = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div class='text-gray-900 mb-2'>
                <span class='text-5xl'>
                    <CountUp start='0' end={props.data} />
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class='text-gray-600 text tracking-wide uppercase'>
                {props.type}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

When I replace `props.data` with an actual number CountUp works fine. But when I use `props.data` its blank.

If I dont use Count up and use just a span with `props.data` it works fine...The component belongs to a larger one as you can see here.

```
import React from 'react';
import CountUp from 'react-countup';

const InsightCard = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div class='text-gray-900 mb-2'>
                <span class='text-5xl'>
                    <CountUp start='0' end={props.data} />
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class='text-gray-600 text tracking-wide uppercase'>
                {props.type}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const Insight = ({ data: { confirmed, death, negative, tested } }) => {
    return (
        <div className='flex flex-col sm:flex-row'>
            <div className='sm:w-1/4 text-center py-8'>
                <div className='border-r'>
                    <InsightCard data={confirmed} type='confirmed cases' />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className='sm:w-1/4 text-center py-8'>
                <div className='border-r'>
                    <InsightCard data={death} type='confirmed deaths' />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className='sm:w-1/4 text-center py-8'>
                <div className='border-r'>
                    <InsightCard data={tested} type='confirmed tests' />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className='sm:w-1/4 text-center py-8'>
                <InsightCard data={negative} type='negative tests' />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Insight;
```

Any ideas or tips would be great thanks.

Comment: There's a good chance that `props.data` isn't being defined. You could also test this by doing `props.data || 100` and if it's always 100, then you know that value isn't defined and perhaps not even a number.

Comment: check the value in the console of `confirmed/death /tested`  and also check props in the `InsightCard `

Comment: @codingwithmanny this has kinda worked...I have done what you suggested. But instead of getting 100 I am getting the actual returned int from the API and works as intended.

Comment: @mrpbennett i have the same issue , did you find any aswer?

Comment: @codingwithmanny I have tested all the things like converting to a number or store it in a variable and pass it, but it did not work. Defining the value of the prop in a normal paragraph it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
const InsightCard = (props) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <div class='text-gray-900 mb-2'>
                    <span class='text-5xl'>
                        <CountUp start='0' end={props.data} />
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class='text-gray-600 text tracking-wide uppercase'>
                    {props.type}
                </div>
            </div>
           );
        };
}
```

I think I found your issue,
could you please check that you have to pass the data that type is **number** because if **props.data** that type is **String** then it can not work.

[Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countup) are the **end** props in **Countup**, it will working for **number**.

Comment: From the API it presents me with an int. Should be working fine. From the above though i have just used `{props.data || 100}` and works fine ... weird

Comment: If the props.data have some value and those value type was Sting then again it's not working. because of if that value type was **number** then it's working

Answer (score 0):

It worked in my test; my guess is it's not being passed to the Insight component correctly from the parent.

```
const data = {
 confirmed: 20,
 death: 10,
 negative: 30,
 tested: 100
} 

return (
 <div>
   <Insight data={data}/>
 </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this to work with the suggestion via @codingwithmanny to test if I was getting 100 or the returned value.

`<CountUp start={0} end={props.data || 100} />` returns the int from the API. I am not sure why this is the case, as without the `|| 100` it didnt return anything.

Comment: if you find why that happened , please let me know!